# Validate DKIM, DMARC SPF, MX DNS records for a domain using a script

Tags: bash, powershell, cmd, dns, network-programming

Trying to accomplish what [MX Toolbox](http://mxtoolbox.com/emailhealth) does except using a CMD/Bash/Python or another type of script. This is so that it becomes possible to validate these records programmatically for multiple domains, schedule it to run at fixed times, etc.

```
    for domain in list_domains:
       validation_output = <do something to validate records for domain and return results (OK or NOT)>
       print("%s: %s", % (domain, validation_output))
    END
```

I don't know how to use a shell to:

1. Check if the MX records point to a valid server
2. Validate SPF record, DMARC record, DKIM record

In fact, I am not sure about what conditions need to be met for validity of the said records.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: This is a rather large programming project, as well as requiring that you understand all of the things you want to validate. I'd recommend searching for packages someone else has written to do this. Otherwise, you have quite a job in front of you.

Answer (score 0):

Not the most reliable solution but you can do something like this

```
for domain in $list_domains
do
    echo "$domain"
    curl -s "https://mxtoolbox.com/emailhealth/$domain/" | grep 'text-error'
done
```

Comment: Hey @diegotorres thanks for this. Curling seems to always give 0 errors no matter what. If I open up https://mxtoolbox.com/emailhealth/example.com/ in the browser, it doesn't show the usual verification report either. Any ideas what can be done to work around this?